# ANTLR4 Assembler Language Parser - issues - miscellaneous comments

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

I am trying to write a parser for the IBM Assembler Language, Example below.

Comment lines start with a star* at the first character, however there are 2 problems

1. Beyond a set point in the line there can also be descriptive text, but there is no star* neccessary.
2. The descriptive can/does contain lexer tokens, such as ENTRY or INPUT.....

   ```
   *        TYPE.                                                          
   ARG      DSECT                                                           
   NXENT    DS    F                    some comment text ENTRY NUMBER             
   NMADR    DS    F                    some comment text INPUT NAME           
   NAADR    DS    F                    some comment text                    
   NATYP    DS    F                    some comment text           
   NAENT    DS    F                    some comment text          
            ORG   NATYP                some comment text
   ```

In my lexer I have devised the following, which works absolutley fine:

```
fragment CommentLine: Star {getCharPositionInLine() == 1}? .*? Nl 
   ;
fragment Star:                '*';
fragment Nl: '\r'? '\n' ;
COMMENT_LINE
   : CommentLine -> channel (COMMENT)
   ;
```

My question is how do I manage the line comments starting at a particular char position in the parser grammer? I.e. Parser -> NAME DS INT? LETTER ??????????

Comment: Assembler source code is strictly line based, right, so I would not use a full blown parser here. Instead split the code by line, then split each line by space and handle the individual tokens then.

Answer (score 0):

Sending comments to a `COMMENT` channel (or `-> skip`ing them) is a technique used to avoid having to define all the places comments are valid in your parser rules.

(Old 360+ Assembler programmer here)

Since there are not really ways to place arbitrarily positioned comments in Assembler source, you don't really need to deal with shunting them off to the side.  Actually because of the way comments are handled in assembler source, there's just NOT a way to identify them in a Lexer rule.

Since it can be a parser rule, you could set up a rule like:

```
trailingComment: (ID | STRING | NUMBER)* EOL;
```

where `ID`, `STRING`, `NUMBER`, etc. are just the tokens in your lexer (You'd need to include pretty much all of them... a good argument, for not getting down to tokens for `MVC`, `CLC`, `CLI`, (all the op codes... the path to madness).  And of course EOL is your rule to match end of line (probably `'\r?\n'`)

You would then end each of your rules for parsing a line that can contain a trailing comment (pretty much all of them) with the `trailingComment` rule.

Comment: Thx both Mikes for replying...neither option is particularly attractive I have to say. I will go away and do some head scratching.

Comment: Just curious... what seems unattractive?  I actually agree with Mike Lischke, BTW.  The context of any syntax is really just a single line (i.e. there aren't syntactically detectable program structures that a parser would help with (a parser won't give a syntax tree that tells you anything of real use re: program structure.))  Forgive the pun, but you really have to "assemble" the program structure by following the branches, and, famously, assembler was pre-structural, so no real guarantees that it doesn't just branch about willy-nilly.  Just the nature of the beast.